# Membermouse - How to display content for a finite period of time, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, membership

I am working on a MemberMouse subscription Wordpress website. On a specific user page I want to display content for a finite period of time. The same should go into a widget.

```
[MM_Member_Decision membershipId='1'  daysAsMember='1' daysAsMember='-3']

**HERE SHOULD BE CONTENT OR A PICTURE** 

[/MM_Member_Decision]
```

Basically, I want to be able to display content for my members for a finite period of time (e.g. 24 hours only).
And I want to be able to do this at any time in a member's life cycle (e.g. 7 days after they joined, 30 days after they joined, etc.)

Usually the SmartTags are looking like above, documentation below:

```
[MM_Member_Decision membershipId='1' daysAsMember='7']
This content will be displayed if the viewing member has been a member of membership level with ID #1 for at least 7 days.
[/MM_Member_Decision]

[MM_Member_Decision membershipId='1' daysAsMember='-10']
This content will be displayed if the viewing member has been a member of membership level with ID #1 for no more than 10 days.
[/MM_Member_Decision]
```

*Even though this is useful, MemberMouse does not allow us to simultaneously define a positive and negative value for the daysAsMember parameter (or the daysWithBundle parameter for that matter).
In other words, if we want to show John our "Super Awesome Content" on day 7 of his membership, and make it invisible again on day 8 (thus making it a 24 hour-only window of availability), we can't do that out of the box with MemberMouse.*

I found this on the web as solution:

```
<?php if(mm_member_decision(array("daysAsMember"=>"1")) && mm_member_decision(array("daysAsMember"=>"-3")) && (mm_member_decision(array("hasBundle"=>"2")) == false)) { echo '"13")) . '">**HERE SHOULD BE CONTENT OR A PICTURE**  ; } ?>
```

You'll notice that the first PHP tag checks to make sure the member has been a member for 1 days.

The second tag checks to make sure that he has not been a member for more than 3 days.

Then we check to make sure he does not have access to bundle with the ID number 2.

And if all of these conditions are met, we display the Text "**HERE SHOULD BE CONTENT OR A PICTURE**".

Then closing out the PHP statement.

So far so good. However, I am trying since a couple of days how to implement this matter into a widget or in a page. Since it is a PHP code it is a little more difficult. Addiontally, I am not sure if the PHP code is even correct. This was just a assumption I found on the web.

Any solution to this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Aron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you would do is create a widget. You can do that using the [Widgets API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API). Then you can put whatever php code you want inside an instance of the widget.

Something like this should get you started (in functions.php or another theme file)

```
class MemberMouseFiniteContent extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct('mm-finite-content',
            'MemberMouse Finite Content',
            array('description' => 'A widget for displaying content in a time window')
        );
    }

    // front-end
    public function widget($args,$instance){
        if( mm_member_decision(array("daysAsMember"=>"1")) 
            && mm_member_decision(array("daysAsMember"=>"-3")) 
            && (mm_member_decision(array("hasBundle"=>"2")) == false)
        ) { 
                echo 'HERE SHOULD BE CONTENT OR A PICTURE';
        }
    }

    public function form($instance){
        // if you want to configure the widget put the form here. 
        // @see https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API
    }

    public function update($new,$old){
        return $new;
    }
}

// register the widget
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
    register_widget( 'MemberMouseFiniteContent' );
});
```